# Java Unable to read csv file on ubuntu machine works on windows?

Tags: java

The below java code simply reads a csv file and sends data to a port 2003 on localhost. I tried this on my Windows machines works fine. However, when i tried to run this file on my ubuntu 14.04 machine i get run time error saying ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Not sure what is wrong i have even give the right path for the csv file on ubuntu ?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
        at parseFile.run(parseFile.java:39)
        at parseFile.main(parseFile.java:19)
```

.

```
Line 37 String[] data = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
Line 38 System.out.println(line);
Line 39
Line 40 String env = data[2];
```

parseFile.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class parseFile {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

      parseFile obj = new parseFile();
     System.out.println("In Main Method");
          obj.run();

  }

  public void run() {

    String csvFile = "/root/javafiles/sum.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = " +";

        System.out.println(csvFile); 
  try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // use space as separator
            String[] data = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
             System.out.println(line); 

            String env = data[2];

            String date = data[0];
            String time = data[1];
            int assigned = Integer.parseInt(data[3]);
            int pooled = Integer.parseInt(data[4]);
            int dbavailable = assigned + pooled;
            int max = Integer.parseInt(data[6]);
            long epoch = 0;
            try {
                String str = "2014-07-04 04:05:10";
                String appenddate= date +" " +time;
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                Date datenew = df.parse(appenddate);
                epoch = datenew.getTime();
                System.out.println(epoch); // 1055545912454
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(env.equals("yy")){

            System.out.println("Sending");  
            Socket conn  = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 2003);
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes("sqldbyp.capacity.assigned "+assigned+" "+epoch+"\n");
            conn.close();
            System.out.println("Sent");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500000);                
                System.out.println("Sleeping for 5 minutes");
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

        }

    }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }
    }

    System.out.println("Done");

 }

}
```

Sum.csv

```
2014-07-04 04:05:10  yy 499 303 24 831 825 0 24 757 858 7
2014-07-04 05:14:09  yy 501 301 24 831 825 0 24 769 865 7
2014-07-04 06:14:47  yy 505 295 24 830 824 0 24 773 870 8
2014-07-04 07:14:09  yy 511 289 24 831 825 0 24 781 875 9
2014-07-04 08:14:10  yy 511 292 23 831 825 0 23 786 881 7
2014-07-04 09:15:02  yy 512 288 23 829 823 0 23 790 886 10
2014-07-04 10:14:10  yy 516 283 24 829 823 0 24 792 897 8
2014-07-04 11:14:10  yy 517 280 24 830 823 0 24 809 906 11
2014-07-04 12:14:09  yy 519 284 23 831 825 0 23 821 915 7
2014-07-04 13:14:10  yy 519 284 23 831 825 0 23 822 922 7
```

Comment: Windows uses other line breaks than Linux, are you aware of that? Because you read line-wise. Also, how is `data` looking for the exception scenario?

Comment: @Smutje this is the first time i am running a java file on a linux machine .. can you please elaborate on the line breaks?

Comment: No, but Wikipedia can: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Common_problems

Comment: You don't need to worry about newline characters, forget it -- java deals with that for you.

Comment: Your CSV file probably has an empty line at the end. Splitting this empty line won't return an array of 2 elements. It's trivial to execute the code step by step using a debugger and to see where the problem comes from. Or even to add traces to know which line causes the problem.

Comment: compiler may get confused if there are mixed types of newline chars in your code, that may be the reason for error being reported at empty line

Comment: thanks for all your help guys indeed there were empty lines in my csv file that confused the compiler.

Comment: @user3846091 the compiler doesn't care about empty lines in a CSV file. Your code had a bug, that's all. The compiler transforms .java files into .class files. It doesn't care about CSV files.

Answer (score 1):

Let's add some checks, and log the data you receive -

```
System.out.println(line); 
String[] data = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
String date = (data != null && data.length > 0) ? data[0] : null;
String time = (data != null && data.length > 1) ? data[1] : null;
String env = (data != null && data.length > 2) ? data[2] : null;
```

Don't forget that you now have to check if your fields are null. You might also prefer

```
if (data == null || data.length < 3) {
  continue;
}
String env = data[2];
String date = data[0];
String time = data[1];
```